# Scrape only hyperlinks that end .ece from an html page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code to scrape only hyperlinks that end with `.ecm`, here is my code

```
_URL='http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2017/08/08/'
r = requests.get(_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
urls = []
names = []
newpath=r'D:\fyp\data set'
os.chdir(newpath)
name='testecmlinks'
for i, link in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
    _FULLURL = _URL + link.get('href')
    if _FULLURL.endswith('.ece'):
        urls.append(_FULLURL)
        names.append(soup.select('a')[i].attrs['href'])

names_urls = zip(names, urls)

for name, url in names_urls:
    print url
    rq = urllib2.Request(url)
    res = urllib2.urlopen(rq)
    pdf = open(name+'.txt', 'wb')
    pdf.write(res.read())
    pdf.close()
```

But I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/fyp/scripts/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    _FULLURL = _URL + link.get('href')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Can you help me get hyperlinks ending with `.ece`?

Comment: Is it `.ece` or `.ecm` you wanna scrape? If it is `.ecm`, can you provide a sample link containing the same?

Comment: sorry its .ece but i get the same error even after the correction

Comment: check    soup.findAll('a')[116].get('href').this will return None.and str nad None cant be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. I hope you will get all the hyperlinks ending with `.ece` from  that page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2017/08/08/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.ece']"):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the result of `link.get('href')` is `None`. The filtering of links can better be done using `Beautiful Soup` directly in the `for` loop. Change your original code

```
...
for i, link in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
    _FULLURL = _URL + link.get('href')
    if _FULLURL.endswith('.ecm'):
        urls.append(_FULLURL)
        names.append(soup.select('a')[i].attrs['href'])
...
```

to this:

```
...
for i, link in enumerate(soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'\.ece$'))):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You get better solutions but with current code you have to check if `link.get('href')` is not `None` before you can add to `_URL`

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    url = link.get('href')  # get `href` or `None`
    if url and url.endswith('.ece'): # check `None` and `.ece'
        names_urls.append( _URL + url, url )
        # ... or directly download file ...
        # rq = urllib2.Request(_URL + url)
        # res = urllib2.urlopen(rq)
        # pdf = open(url+'.txt', 'wb')
        # pdf.write(res.read())
        # pdf.close()
```